# Need help accessing my Sun Netra X1

Tags: networking, solaris-10

I have a Netra X1 running Solaris 10 that I need help accessing. A friend set it up for me originally (with Terminal via the serial port, I think). He gave it a fixed IP, 192.168.0.200, or 1.200.. and I used to ssh to it.

It has sat in the loft a couple of years. It powers on and I can hear the HDD working. There is no fault light. I think it's operational. But I cannot ping it, or see it listed as an Ethernet connection on my router's admin page.

Since I last used it, I have had to replace my old, ailing NetGear hub with a BT HomeHub.

I realise now the initial configuration probably went in the bin with the NetGear router, but I need this confirmed, as I'm a software engineer by trade, and less knowledgeable about the metal and real networking.

How is a machine like my Netra X1 given a fixed IP? Is it router settings? If it is router settings, what am I looking for on my BT HomeHub? If it's not router settings, the machine should still be accessible, and so I need help making a diagnosis. This may involve learning about the LOM port?

My primary goal is to retrieve the contents of the SVN repository on this machine.

My secondary goal is to get the machine back in service - I have my eye on some quieter fans for it. =)

Comment: you could try using tcpdump from another machine, to try to catch your netra's IP, or use an ip scanner if you know its subnet.

Comment: @scottw Do you have another computer you can put on the same network?  What is its IP?

Comment: @scottw the Nextra's IP is set via its configuration files.   I assume you can't login via the console.

Comment: @sivann - I don't see the Netra's or any other unknown IPs listed by tcpdump, and I do not know its subnet.

Comment: @Ron - The MacBook I am using now is on 192.168.1.68. By console, do you mean via a serial connection to the LOM port on the rear of the Netra? I am awaiting a Cisco console cable in the post. I hope to form a serial connection with Putty or similar when it arrives. I haven't done that before. Will I login as normal and have access to the whole box like via a regular SSH connection? If the IP is configured on the Netra itself, how do I know what it should be to be recognised by my BT HomeHub?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Netgear router again and can now connect to my Netra.

It's been a while:

Last login: Sat Dec 10 12:40:46 2011 from 192.168.0.3
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
[scott@sparc ~]$

=)

The machine was given an IP address of 192.168.0.200 when I brought it home. My BT HomeHub seems to have had a range of 192.168.1.*, so it wasn't detecting the Netra when I made an ethernet connection.

I could have made a serial connection to the Netra, as advised, and changed its fixed IP - and I am going to learn to do that - but switching to the Netgear router 'fixed' the problem as by default it has a DHCP range of 192.168.0.2, up to .0.254 - so the Netra's fixed IP was visible, and I was able to ssh to it.

On the plus side, I now have a router I can actually configure - as opposed to the BT HomeHub which seems to be a locked down 'SpeedTouch' modem with no restore to factory settings feature or known login details (I tried the top google suggestions, no joy, so I was not able to change its DHCP range..)

Thanks.